# Is there any network/paper used to analyse music scores?

Tags: neural-networks, computer-vision, generative-adversarial-networks

As I am curious on music theory I would like to know that If is there any such network that analyse like labeling chords, or doing a roman numeral analysis.

Like an example below:

[image]

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numeral_analysis)

It does not seem to be a difficult task.

Some other examples are given [here](http://bachchoraleharmony.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/J.S.Bach-413-Chorales-Analyzed_Preview-4.pdf)[external link]

Also I am curious that If it is a possible task for AI to accomplish.

Comment: I think that you should try RBM's if you intend to make the machine make the music.

Comment: I have heard them make poems, but not something as you said.

Comment: Sorry if I understood and guessed it wrong.

Comment: Actually I do not want to generate music scores, I want to label them as like as YOLO does. Thank you for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not come across music labeling algorithms but upon a google [scholar](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/301311636.pdf#page=40) search, I found a couple of papers that aim to do quite the same task.

In general, if you have a labeled dataset then you can take an approach of a general speech recognition model. It should work fine for music labeling too, but you might need to tweak certain parameters.